# How do i calculate 26 + log (base 2)4 in java

Tags: java, logging, logarithm

26 + log (base 2)4.

How to calculate this in java.

```
np= (26 + log(2))*4;
System.out.println(np);
```

I have done this but it is showing garbage value. The answer should be 28.

Comment: Did you search on Google before asking here?

Comment: `log(base 2) 4` is `log(4)/log(2)`

Comment: yes but no answer to this type of question

Comment: What more of an answer do you want? Your initial math was wrong, and Faibbus noted the correct math. So... just type that in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log (base 2)4 is the same as **log10(4)/ log10(2)**

so you can use the java.lang.Math class to calculate that

```
System.out.println(26 +Math.log10(4)/Math.log10(2));
```

the result: 28.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a math relation : log_2(x) = **log_10(x)/log_10(2)** or = **ln(x)/ln(2)**

So it gaves :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 26;
        int b = 4;
        double valLog_2;

        valLog_2= Math.log(b)/Math.log(2);
        //OR
        valLog_2 = Math.log10(b)/Math.log10(2);

        System.out.println(a+valLog_2);
    }
```